# Forcing a graph not to resize

Tags: graphics, graphs-and-networks, dynamic

This code:

```
Clear[ighamiltMol,timeList,hamiltMol,];

timeList={Abs[0.333333 E^(-I t) + 0.333333 E^(I t) + 0.166667 E^(-2 I t) + 
   0.166667 E^(2 I t)]^2, 
 Abs[0.\[VeryThinSpace]+ 0.166667 E^(-I t) - 0.166667 E^(I t) + 
   0.166667 E^(-2 I t) - 0.166667 E^(2 I t)]^2, 
 Abs[-0.166667 E^(-I t) - 0.166667 E^(I t) + 0.166667 E^(-2 I t) + 
   0.166667 E^(2 I t)]^2, 
 Abs[-0.333333 E^(-I t) + 0.333333 E^(I t) + 0.166667 E^(-2 I t) - 
   0.166667 E^(2 I t)]^2, 
 Abs[0.\[VeryThinSpace]- 0.166667 E^(-I t) - 0.166667 E^(I t) + 
   0.166667 E^(-2 I t) + 0.166667 E^(2 I t)]^2, 
 Abs[0.166667 E^(-I t) - 0.166667 E^(I t) + 0.166667 E^(-2 I t) - 
       0.166667 E^(2 I t)]^2}

hamiltMol={{0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1,
   0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1}, {1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0}}

ighamiltMol = 
  Dynamic@AdjacencyGraph[hamiltMol, 
    VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Tooltip], 
    GraphStyle -> "SpringEmbedding", 
    VertexShapeFunction -> (Disk[#1, timeList[[#2]]] &)];

Animator[Dynamic[t], {0, 19}, .5]
ighamiltMol
```

Generates this animation (2 pictures shown, notice the resizing):
[image: Mathematica graphics]
[image: Mathematica graphics]

I would like my disks' radii not to exceed 2/3 of the distance between two vertices, so that the graph needs no resizing.

The same method applied to `GraphPlot[]` and `GraphPlot3D[]` also does not work, producing results like those obtained with `AdjacencyGraph[]`. I've tried setting a `DataRange->{}`, but it doesn't work either. `Rescale[]`ing didn't work.

(Note that this is not a problem in a `Graphics[]` environment.)

I don't know what to try next.

Comment: Your pasted code is incomplete. E.g. in the first snippet, `hamiltMol`and `timeCoeff` are not defined.

Comment: They are - commented out. `hamiltMol` is an adjacency matrix and `timeCoeff[]` looks in a table containing complex exponentials, one per vertex. The problem occurs even with a square and a `Sin[]` varying disk radius.

Comment: Working code will get you more takers. Just paste in a toy example, if the original is too complex.

Comment: @YvesKlett The code has been edited.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming that `timecoeff` is scaled between 0 and 1 you could do something like this (I just made something up for `timecoeff` and `hamiltMol`):

```
Clear[ighamiltMol, t]; t = 0;
timeCoeff[i_] := (1 + Sin[t + 2.5 i])/2
hamiltMol = NestList[RotateRight, {0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1}, 5];

ighamiltMol = 
 Dynamic@AdjacencyGraph[hamiltMol,(*hamiltMol is a symmetric sparse/
   adjacency matrix*)
   EdgeShapeFunction -> (Line[#1] &),
   VertexLabels -> Placed["Name", Tooltip], 
   GraphStyle -> "SpringEmbedding", 
   VertexShapeFunction -> ({{Opacity[0], Disk[#1, #3]},
       Disk[#1, #3 timeCoeff[#2] ]} &),
   VertexSize -> 
    4/3];(*timeCoeff[] looks in a list of complex \
exponentials*)Animator[Dynamic[t], {0, 2 Pi}, .1]
ighamiltMol
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This works by using a `VertexShapeFunction` which consists of two disks on top of each other, namely a transparent one with a fixed radius, and a solid one with a varying radius. The option `VertexSize -> 4/3` makes sure that the maximum radius is equal to 2/3 time the mimimum length of all vertices.

Comment: Changing `VertexSize` doesn't work for me, neither does adding a normalization factor to `timeCoeff[]`. I think the problem lies in the space that's allocated for the graph by `Mathematica` - it's constantly updated. What I'd like is for the graph to be centered in a wider canvas, so there's no need to resize.

Comment: The invisible disks should prevent the size of the graph from changing as `t` changes. `VertexSize` only works in combination with multiplying the radius of the disks with the third argument supplied to `VertexShapeFunction`.

Comment: Turns out `EdgeShapeFunction` was essential. Thank you =)

Comment: Heike, congratulations on the first tag badge!